# Understanding how bootmem works

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot

I have been studying OS concepts and decided to look in how these stuff are actually implemented in Linux. But I am having problem understanding some thing in relation with memory management during boot process before `page_allocator` is turned on, more precisely how `bootmem` works. I do not need the exact workings of it, but just an understanding how some things are/can be solved.

So obviously, `bootmem` cannot use dynamic memory, meaning that size he has must be known before runtime, so appropriate steps can be taken, i.e. the maximum size of his bitmap must be known in advance. From what I understand, this is most likely solved by simply mapping enough memory during kernel initialization, if architecture changes, simply change the size of the mapped memory. Obviously, there is probably a lot more going on, but I guess I got the general idea? However, what really makes no sense to me is NUMA architecture. Everywhere I read, it says that `pg_data_t` is created for each memory node. This `pg_data` is put into a list(how can it know the size of the list? Or is the size fixed for specific arch?) and for each node, bitmap is allocated. So, basically, it sounds like it can create undefined number of these `pg_data`, each of which has their memory bitmap of arbitrary size. How? What am I missing?

EDIT: Sorry for not including reference. Here is `bootmem` code, it can also be found in `mm/bootmem.c`: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/bootmem.c

Comment: You mean the NUMA architecture? I do not know, it is not important I guess, I am just interested how it is conceptually solved. EDIT: more specifically, the problem with arbitrary number of `pg_data` structures.

Comment: What no, which processor architecture? x86, ARM, PowerPC, MIPS, x86-64, whatever. Or is that completely architecture-independent code? Where in the source tree can we find the code?

Comment: Well you can see it here, parts of it specifically. https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand022.html. It is taken from mm/bootmem.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this more, I think it works this way: basically, all the necessary things are statically allocated, i.e. by using preprocessor DEFINES it is ensured certain sections of `bootmem` (as well as other parts of the kernel) code either exist or do not exist in the compiled code for specific architecture (even though the code itself is architecture-independent). These DEFINES are specified in architecture-dependent sources codes found under arch/ (e.g. arch/i386, arch/arm/, etc.). For NUMA architectures there is a define called MAX_NUMNODES, ensuring that list of structs (more specifically, list of `pg_data_t` structures) representing nodes is allocated as a static array (which is then treated as a list). The bitmaps representing memory map are obviously relatively small, since each page is represented as only one bit, taking up KBs, or maybe MBs. Whatever the case, architecture dependent `head.S` sets-up all the necessary structures needed for system functioning (like page-tables) and ensure enough physical memory is mapped to virtual so these bitmaps can fit in it without causing page-fault (in case of x86 arch, initial 8MB of RAM is mapped, which is more then enough for both kernel and additional structures, like bitmaps).

Answer (score 0):

It is architecture-dependent. On the x86 architecture, early on in the boot process the kernel does issue *one* BIOS call - the `0xe820` function of the trap at Interrupt Vector `0x15`. This returns a memory map that the kernel can use to build it's memory tables, including holes for non-memory (PCI or ISA) devices, etc. Bootloaders (before the kernel) will do the same.

See: [Detecting Memory](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86))

Comment: No not really, I understood that part is architecture-dependent. The part with memory bitmap allocation is a bit unclear. How does it know how much memory it will need for the map?

Comment: @Mudrac Maybe by checking the returned data by the BIOS call. A 32-bit x86 processor without PAE enabled can address at most 4 GiB anyway, so a statically-sized bitmap might also be possible.

Comment: @cad I don't think it is possible. Since dynamic allocation is not possible at that moment in time. So it seems it must pre-allocate enough memory. EDIT: Ok, I guess statically-sized bitmap makes sense. So it just needs to know the max max_mem_size for given arch and then map enough memory for worst case scenario?

Comment: I just checked the source code. Actually, it tries some combination of three calls while `0xe820` is still the first option.

Comment: To my recollection, 0xe820 is the "newest", but since some "older" machines (and we probably mean VERY old) might not support it - it can fall-back to the others. (For all I know, there might even be something NEWER than 0xe820, but not to my knowledge)

Comment: No, no, that part really is not the problem. It depends on architecture what and how is it exactly called. But the code I linked, sets-up the `bootmem`, i.e. allocator used during bootstrap process in architecture-independent way by creating memory bitmaps which are then used for allocating memory. BUT, but, it must know the size of these maps in advance, so enough memory is mapped before it is loaded. For UMA arch I imagine this is solved by knowing the maximum size of the said bitmap array and simply creating enough entries in statically allocated page table. But, how si it solved for NUMA?

Comment: @Mudrac `bootmem.c` seems to include `linux/slab.h` and calls `kzalloc` some times, so apparently, the slab allocator has already been initialized.

Comment: @Mudrac There's also the function `bootmem_bootmap_pages`, which calculates the bitmap's size.